# Java new keyword

Tags: java, oop, object

I have a small problem with my java project.

Here is the correct code:

```
Common c = new Common("C",10);

Client c1 = new Client(c);
Thread newClientThread = new Thread(c1);
newClientThread.start();
newCLientThread.join();
```

If i try to write this on less rows it will look like:

```
Common c = new Common("C",10);
new Thread(new Client(c)).start();          //starts the thread
```

now, how am i gonna write the thread.join?

something like Thread(Client).join

Comment: Thread thread = new Thread(new Client(c)); thread.start(); thread.join();

Comment: This is neither possible nor advised for readability reasons. You can inline the `Common` and `Client` variables, though.

Comment: Code for readability first. There is virtually no benefit whatsoever from trying to cram as much as possible into a single line.

Comment: Thank you, now is clear for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no benefit to packing as much as possible into a line of code. Separate it out as much as possible, make it easy to read.

Strictly speaking, there is no need to call join() in this instance. The purpose of join is to make one thread wait for another thread to finish, but it's a pretty crude form of checkpointing. Since the JVM will exit anyway when your started thread ends and this is the desired behavior, you don't need to explicitly call it.

Comment: Uh??? No it is the very standard usage of threads. It is a very common behavior to wait until the end of some slave thread. While you don't know what the thread is doing you cannot give such an advice.